# Orchard CMS - Text visible on every page & editable in CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I would like to add in the top right of every page - contact phone & email link.

They are styled uniquely on the page by CSS - based on their containing DIV's class.

What is the best practice way to make that visible on every page - and editable in the CMS?

Would I have to have the HTML markup editable too (the client is non technical)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add a HTML widget on the default layer. You can give it custom classes etc. and style it within your theme.